how to activate the remote controlling function of Fanuc LRMate200iC?
I am trying to connect to the Fanuc LRMate 200iC robot using RoboDK. The connection could be established but the program did not run on the robot. It does not do any movement on the remote control option. However, it perfectly works with online programming using the teaching pendant. I am guessing that there is some configuration that I have to adjust on the robot so that it responds to remote controlling as well. Does anyone know how to adjust this? Thanks.
